# At which point does `for` or `for /R` enumerate the directory (tree)?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

The command `for` can be used to enumerate a directory and apply (a) certain command(s) on each item. With the `/R` the same can be accomplished for a full directory tree.

What happens when the content of the enumerated directory (tree) is changed by the command(s) in the body of the `for` command?

Supposed we have the directory `D:\data` with the following content:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

The output of `for %F in ("*.txt") do echo %F` when executed in said directory will reflect the above list obviously.

However, what is the output of the `for` loop when a command in the `for` body modifies the content of the directory? For instance, one of the files in the list is deleted, let's say `file3.txt`, before it is actually iterated? Or if a new file is created, like `file4.txt`, before completion of the loop?

How does `for /R` behave in that context? Supposed there are several sub-directories `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3`, each containing the above list of files; `for /R` is currently iterating through `sub2`, `sub1` has already been processed, but `sub3` not yet; the contents of `sub1` and `sub3` are changed at that point (when currently walking through `sub2` as mentioned); what will be enumerated then? I guess, the change of the content of `sub1` won't be recognised, but what about `sub3`?

Finally, is there a difference in behaviour of `for` or `for /R` when being executed in the command prompt or from a batch file? And are there differences in different Windows versions?

**Note:**
See also my [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32080023/5047996) about the `forfiles` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an excellent question!

Let's concentrate on plain `for` command for a moment. There is a known bug related to this command when it is used to *rename files*. For example:

```
set i=0
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   ren "%%a" !i!.txt
)
```

In this case is frequently that certain files be renamed twice, and even three times in certain cases. The problem is that this behavior depends on a series of factors that are not documented, like the position of the first renamed file inside the list of original files and several other points. Similarly, if a file is deleted before it is processed by the `for`, a "File not found" message is *usually* issued (although not ALL times). If a new file is created in the directory *after* the `for` started execution, then it may or may not be processed by the `for` depending (again) on a series of factors. The usual way to avoid the problem with rename is to force `for` command to first read the whole list of files and *then* process the list:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do (
   set /A i+=1
   ren "%%a" !i!.txt
)
```

This way, don't matters the changes that can be made on the files in the disk: the `for /F` command will always process the *original* file list.

A similar problem happen with `for /R` command, but in this case the possibility of problems is greater because there are more directories where dynamic changes can be made. Again: the exact behavior depends on a series of unknown factors and the way to avoid them is via `for /F ... in ('dir /S /B')`. However, if you are *really* interested in this point, I encourage you to made a series of tests on the subject (and post the results). **`;)`**

Comment: Thanks for that extensive explanation! When you're talking about a "known bug", could you please provide any references, if possible? Or are the described problems your own experiences? Perhaps I will do intensive testing on that topic someday, but for the moment, my quintessence is: in case of doublts, use the `for /F` work-around.

Comment: The info was taken from several posts in various sites, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950081/windows-batch-file-loop-running-one-extra-iteration): "The operation depends on quite what prefix is added. A prefix starting "a" works differently from a prefix starting "x". AND the result depends on the filesystem being used. NTFS presents the filenames alphabetically but the FAT system on the RAMDRIVE doesn't sort the names". A more detailed description of this point is [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4138&sid=463cb91964f497c478afcca79c33384a)