# Change extension of files in windows batch

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, rename

I am trying to rename a lot of files. I only want to change the extention from ".pdf.OCR.pdf" to ".pdf"
So far I got the following code

```
rem for /r myPDFfolder %%i in (*.pdf.OCR.pdf) do ren "%%i" "%%~ni.pdf"
```

But it does not appear to work with the extension that has multiple dots -- what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extension is the part of file name after the *last* dot.

Use string replacement to strip the unneeded part:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b "r:\*.pdf.OCR.pdf"') do (
    set "name=%%~nxi"
    ren "%%i" "!name:.pdf.OCR=!"
)
```

P.S. Parsing of `dir` is used to make the code more robust in case a different text is stripped which might have changed the sorting order and cause `for` to process the file twice or more times.

Comment: I'd use replacement `!file:.pdf.OCR.pdf=.pdf!` to fully comply with the original question...

Comment: That would be an overly literal interpretation. The goal was to *strip* the unneeded part. Actually an even shorter method might be used: `set name=%%~ni` and `ren "%%i" "!name:.OCR=!"`, so the code is already superfluous to be more obvious.

Comment: ...okay, I agree... anyway, you should place `"` around the entire `set` expression to avoid trouble with special characters like `^` or `&` in the file names; and I recommend to enuerate the directory by `dir /S /B /A:-D` and parse its output by `for /F` rather than using `for /R` to ensure the directory tree to be enumerated `before` iterating through it; since you are modifying the tree in the `for /R` body, conflicts may arise (see my [post about that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093/5047996))...

Comment: Thanks, I'll add quotes and use `dir` to make the code more robust for someone else's needs. However *luckily* in this particular case there was no need for `dir` because the new file name doesn't change the sorting order.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Actually, the sort order is not important, especially since the list is not guaranteed to be processed in any particular order if it is on a fat file system. However, it still should be safe because the renamed file should not match the `*.pdf.ocr.pdf` file mask.

Comment: ...unless it's `*.pdf.ocr.pdf.ocr.pdf`, @dbenham??

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a batch file. A moderate length one liner from the command prompt can do the trick.

If you know for a fact that all files that match `*.pdf.ocr.pdf` have this exact case: `.pdf.OCR.pdf`, then you can use the following from the command line:

```
for /r "myPDFfolder" %F in (.) do @ren "%F\*.pdf.ocr.pdf" *O&ren "%F\*.pdf.o" *f
```

The first rename removes the trailing `.pdf`, and the second removes the `.OCR`. The above works because `*O` in the target mask preserves everything in the original file name through the last occurrence of upper-case `O`, and `*f` preserves through the last occurrence of lower-case `f`. Note that the characters in the source mask are not case sensitive. You can read more about how this works at [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards/475875#475875)

If the case of `.pdf.ocr.pdf` can vary, then the above will fail miserably. But there is still a one liner that works from the command line:

```
for /r "myPDFfolder" %F in (*.pdf.ocr.pdf) do @for %G in ("%~nF") do @ren "%F" "%~nG"
```

`%~nF` lops off the last `.pdf`, and `%~nG` lops off the `.OCR`, which leaves the desired extension of `.pdf`.

You should not have to worry about a file being renamed twice because the result after the rename will not match `*.pdf.ocr.pdf` unless the original file looked like `*.pdf.ocr.pdf.ocr.pdf`.

If you think you might want to frequently rename files with complex patterns in the future, then you should look into [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a regular expression renaming utility. It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

Assuming JREPL.BAT is in a folder that is listed within your PATH, then the following simple command will work from the command line, only renaming files that match the case in the search string:

```
jren "(\.pdf)\.OCR\.pdf$" $1 /s /p "myPDFfolder"
```

If you want to ignore case when matching, but want to force the extension to be lower case, then:

```
jren "\.pdf\.ocr\.pdf$" ".pdf" /i /s /p "myPDFfolder"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, without [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) (remove `ECHO` to actually rename any files):

```
@echo off
rem iterate over all matching files:
for /F "delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /S /B /A:-D "myPDFfolder\*.pdf.OCR.pdf"'
) do (
  rem "%%~nA" removes last ".pdf"
  for /F %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
    rem "%%~nB" removes ".OCR" part
    for /F %%C in ("%%~nB") do (
      rem "%%~nC" removes remaining ".pdf"
      ECHO ren "%%~fA" "%%~nC.pdf"
    ) & rem next %%C
  ) & rem next %%B
) & rem next %%A
```

**NOTE:** The directory tree is enumerated *before* `for` iterates through it because otherwise, some items might be skipped or tried to be renamed twice (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976922/5047996) concerning that issue).

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about files being renamed twice in this case. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32282125/1012053)