# Batch Script - Rename files, removing a variable prefix and suffix

Tags: batch-file

I have several files in a folder with names like

```
"prefix (S-N 12RE3123) suffix.pdf"
```

I would like to rename them to just `"12RE3123.pdf"`, removing the prefix and suffix.  The issue is that both the prefix and suffix are of varying lengths/ characters, so I cannot just rename by removing the first/last xx characters, but have to use the only commonality where only the characters inside the parenthesis following `"S-N"` are those to be kept.

There is one special case where a few of the serial numbers are named as `WD-12RE3123`, and I need to remove the `WD-` as well.  If I had to do it manually, there aren't a lot of them like that so it wouldn't be the end of the world, but having it automated would be nice.  I thought of maybe doing an if statement after the removal of prefix/suffix to check if the first 3 characters match `WD-` then remove those if true, but I am not sure on the implementation.

I am still a novice in batch or vbscript, so I was wondering if this can be done in either of those.  Batch has the method "`REN`" to rename files, but since the final name depends upon what the current name is I am not sure how to set up delimiters or how to approach this.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `prefix` and `suffix` do *not* contain any parentheses on their own, you could use `for /F "eol=| tokens=2 delims=()" %%L in ('dir /B "*.pdf"') do ...` to retrieve the portion of interest (see also `for /?`); if they *do* contain parenthesis, it is going to be more complicated; the rest can be done with substring replacement (see `set /?`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for your request. It relies on the following facts:

- the `prefix` portion does not contain any parenthesis `(` or `)` on its own (`suffix` might though);
- the serial number does not contain any parentheses `(` or `)` on its own;
- there are no duplicate serial numbers, also with respect to removal of potentional `WD-` strings;

This is the code (after having tested the code on the files in your target folder, you need to remove the upper-case `ECHO` command to actually rename the files):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Set constants here:
set "LOCATION=.\test"
set "PATTERN=*.pdf"
set STRINGS="S-N " "WD-"

cd /D "%LOCATION%"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%K in ('dir /B "%PATTERN%"') do (
    for /F "eol=| tokens=2 delims=()" %%L in ("%%~nK") do (
        set "NAME=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%J in (%STRINGS%) do (
            if "!NAME!"=="%%~J!NAME:*%%~J=!" (
                set "NAME=!NAME:*%%~J=!"
            )
        )
        ECHO ren "%%~fK" "!NAME!%%~xK"
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

How it works:

- the first section specifies the folder location, the file pattern and the strings to remove (after having extracted the portion within `()`); adapt the values to your needs;
- there are several nested `for` loops; the outermost one simply iterates all the files matching the given pattern (it basically reads and parses the output of a `dir` command applied on the given files and loops through the returned items; opposed to a standard `for` loop, this `for /F` method ensures that the entire folder is read before the loop starts iterating, which is necessary when modifying the enumerated folder content like we do here by renaming files; see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093) about that issue);

  - the next `for /F` loop extracts the file name portion of interest, that is everything between the first pair of parenthesis, and stores it in variable `NAME`; this loop iterates once only per file;

    - the is another `for` loop which walks though all items in the `STRINGS` variable;

      - the `if` clause checks whether the current item of `STRINGS` occurs at the very beginning of the `NAME` value; if so, it is removed, otherwise not; this is just a safety query because perhaps a serial number might also contain a given `STRINGS` item in the middle or at the end (for instance, `123-WD-45A`);
    - at this point, the renaming is performed (after having removed `ECHO`, of course);
    - the toggling of [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905) is intended to avoid trouble with some special characters in the file names;

---

And here is another script that uses a more complex method for extracting the interesting parts of the file names. It relies on the following facts:

- there occurs only a single substring `(S-N`<kbd>SPACE</kbd> in the file name
- the serial number is followed by a `)`;
- the serial number does not contain any parentheses `(` or `)` on its own;
- there are no duplicate serial numbers, also with respect to removal of potentional `WD-` strings;

The code looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Set constants here:
set "LOCATION=.\test"
set "PATTERN=*.pdf"
set "FILTER=(S-N [^()][^()]*)"
set "IDENTIFYER=S-N "
set STRINGS="WD-"

cd /D "%LOCATION%"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%K in ('
    dir /B "%PATTERN%" ^| findstr /I /R /C:"%FILTER%"
') do (
    set "NAME=%%K"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "NAME=!NAME:*(%IDENTIFYER%=!"
    for /F "eol=| tokens=1 delims=)" %%L in ("!NAME!") do (
        setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        set "NAME=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%J in (%STRINGS%) do (
            if "!NAME!"=="%%~J!NAME:*%%~J=!" (
                set "NAME=!NAME:*%%~J=!"
            )
        )
        ECHO ren "%%~fK" "!NAME!%%~xK"
        endlocal
        endlocal
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Basically, this script works similar to the above one, with a few deviations:

- the first section specifies a file name filter and the serial number identifyer (`S-N`) in addition;
- the `dir` command in the outermost `for` loop is piped into a `findstr` command to filter out files not containing `(S-N` and `)` and a string (not containing `(`/`)`) in between already at the beginning;

  - the part `(S-N` and everything before is removed, the result is stored in `NAME`;
  - the next `for /F` loop extracts everything up to but not including the first `)` from the `NAME` value, which constitutes the file name portion of interest; this loop iterates once only per file;

    - the is another `for` loop which walks though all items in the `STRINGS` variable, which does not contain the `S-N` portion here as this has already been removed before; the rest in this loop is the same as in the above script;
    - at this point, the renaming is performed (after having removed `ECHO`, of course);

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*(*)*.*" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=()" %%c IN ("%%a") DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=- " %%m IN ("%%d") DO (
   IF "%%o"=="" (ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%%n%%~xa"
   ) ELSE (
    ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%%o%%~xa"
   )
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Apply each filename matching the mask "*(*)*.*" to `%%a`

Tokenise using `(` and `)` as delimiters so that the parenthesised portion is in `%%d`
Re-tokenise using `-` and  as delimiters so that the required number is in `%%o` for `S-N` patterns and `%%n` for `WD-` pattern.

Show the rename line.

Note: this should work provided the `prefix` portion does not contain parentheses and the parenthesised portion is exactly as described.

Answer (score 1):

Magoo and aschipfl both provided good pure batch solutions.

I find development of custom batch scripts for every complex renaming task to be tedious, which is why I wrote [JREN.BAT - a regex find/replace renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). JREN.BAT is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is available from the command line via `jren /?`, or use `jren /??` for paged help.

With JREN.BAT, the solution is as simple as (untested):

```
jren "^.*\((?:S-N (?:WD-)?)(.+?)\).*" "$1.jpg" /fm *.jpg
```

If I got the regex wrong, it can easily be fixed. You should probably add the `/T` option to run the command in test mode first, and then remove it when everything looks good.

If you put the command in a batch script, then you must use CALL JREN.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the `(?:S-N |WD-)` portion should read `(?:S-N |S-N WD-)` or `(?:S-N (?:WD-)?)` as (at least in my interpretation) even serial numbers starting with `WD-` are preceded by `S-N `...

Comment: @aschipfl - Upon reading the question more carefully, I now agree with you. Edit made. Thanks.