# Modifying a variable in Windows Batch Language

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, substring

I am writing a batch file to convert music files and have saved a file name in a variable. A couple of examples would be:
`David Bowie - Space Oddity.mp3`
Or maybe
`David Bowie - Greatest Hits - Space Oddity.mp3`

I'd like to edit the variable so it just contains the track name `Space Oddity`. So I need to search backwards from the end until I reach the first occurrence of `{Hyphen}{Space}`, and discard everything that comes before it, *(since the variable might contain more than one hyphen)*.

Please could you suggest some batch code to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch Script - Rename files, removing a variable prefix and suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612196/batch-script-rename-files-removing-a-variable-prefix-and-suffix) Specifically, you need substring replacement with a wildcard. It will look something like `set "mp3_name=%mp3_name:*- =%"` and you will have to do this more than once depending on how many instances of ` - ` you want to remove. Also, for renaming music files, I'd recommend existing software like FileBot or TagScanner.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this is](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10802#p68477) the simplest way:

```
for %%a in ("%filename: - =\%") do set "track=%%~Na"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "var=David Bowie - Space Oddity.mp3"
FOR %%e IN ("%var%") DO SET "var=%%~ne"
FOR %%e IN ("%var:- =.%") DO SET "var=%%~xe"
SET "var=%var:~1%"
SET var
ECHO ---------------
SET "var=David Bowie - Greatest Hits - Space Oddity.mp3"
FOR %%e IN ("%var%") DO SET "var=%%~ne"
FOR %%e IN ("%var:- =.%") DO SET "var=%%~xe"
SET "var=%var:~1%"
SET var
ECHO ---------------
SET "var=Voices in the Sky - The Best of the Moody Blues The Moody Blues 05 - I'm Just a Singer (In a Rock and Roll Band).mp3"
FOR %%e IN ("%var%") DO SET "var=%%~ne"
FOR %%e IN ("%var:- =.%") DO SET "var=%%~xe"
SET "var=%var:~1%"
SET var

GOTO :EOF
```

The first `for` removes the extension; the second modifies each `-`  to `.` and then grabs the extension and the final `set` removes the leading `.`.

All based on `for /?` from the prompt - using the string as a filename and using standard interpretations of what constitutes the various parts of a filename (drive, path, name and extension).

Comment: [... and then there are titles that contain dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y.M.C.A._(song)) (sorry for tainting your answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the assistance of a more complete scripting language, such as PowerShell:

Examples:

```bash
@Set "FileName=David Bowie - Space Oddity.mp3"
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "('%FileName%' -Split '- ')[-1]"
@Pause
```

```bash
@Set "FileName=David Bowie - Greatest Hits - Space Oddity.mp3"
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "('%FileName%' -Split '- ')[-1]"
@Pause
```

If you wanted the substring to be re-propagated into the variable name then use a `FOR /F` loop.

Example:

```bash
@Set "FileName=David Bowie - Greatest Hits - Space Oddity.mp3"
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command
 "('%FileName%' -Split '- ')[-1]"') Do @Set "FileName=%%~nG"
@Set Filename
@Pause
```