# Batch rename specific files adding char to filename

Tags: batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I want to add "a" to specific place in a filename for some, but not all files in a dir.

The files are all pdf files, and have different numbers as filename with the following formats:
x.pdf 
    or 
x_x.pdf

x can range from 1-999. The files to be renamed are all files that has 2 or 3 chars after a "_". The new filename should have a "a" after the _ 
In this example, bold files should be have a "a" after the _

0.pdf
**0_34.pdf** 
10.pdf
10_1.pdf 
**10_10.pdf** 
**10_111.pdf**

Im trying to do something like `IF exist *_??.pdf ren *_a??.pdf (` 
or creating a loop `for %%o in (*_??.pdf) do ren "%%o" "*_a??.pdf"` 
and then do one with three ???. It doesn't look like im very close, and therefor I ask you guys for help! :)

Comment: This does not solve the problem, but: as input mask you could use `?*_??*.pdf` (at least one char. before `_`, at least two char.s after `_`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```dos
for /F "eol=| tokens=1,* delims=_" %%E in ('
    dir /B /A:-D "?*_??*.pdf" ^| findstr /I /R /C:"^[0-9][0-9]*_[0-9][0-9][0-9]*\.pdf$"
') do (
    ECHO ren "%%E_%%F" "%%E_a%%F"
)
```

Here I am using `for /F` rather than a standard `for` loop because the directory content is modified while the loop iterates, which could cause trouble, according to this: [At which point does `for` or `for /R` enumerate the directory (tree)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093). With `for /F` parsing the output of `dir /B`, the directory content is read *before* any items are renamed.

The `findstr` command line constitutes an additional filter here, so only files following your naming rules are affected by the rename. Remove the `findstr` command and `^|` if you do not want that.

For testing purposes I added `ECHO` to the `ren` command, hence to rename any files, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

ren is a very quirky command. Someone did a complete study of it here https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards

Or you could use Bulk rename command   http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Command.php