# Batch script to search multiple directory and move it to a specific folder

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a script that searches a multiple directory "eg: TEST" and move it to a specific location in a folder. I have tried using the below script. It display the folder location 
example:

```
"E:\Example\TEST"
"E:\TEST\TEST"
```

Please check the script i have created. Can anyone help?

```
@echo off

set filename=TEST

set searchPath=E:\

set Destination= E:\FOUND

FOR /R "%searchPath%" %%a  in (%filename%) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~fa" (
        echo "%%~fa"
    )
)

move "%%~fa" "%Destination%"
```

Comment: `for`/`for /R` accesses the file system only in case wild-cards are present in the part/set within `()`; and `for`/`for /R` enumerates files unless you provide the `/D` switch...

Comment: Remove the space after `=` equals in `set` command. Moreover, use `set "Destination=E:\FOUND"` to ensure that there is no unwanted trailing space .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. Since you are trying to move directories, the directory tree enumerated by `for /R` is modified. `for`/`for /R` however does not enumerate the directory (tree) in advance, therefore unexpected results may occur -- see the following question for details about that: [At which point does `for` or `for /R` enumerate the directory (tree)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093).
2. `for` or `for /R` accesses the file system only in case there are wildcards given in the set (that is the part in between parentheses).
3. It is not perfectly clear what exactly you want to accomplish:

   - what should happen in case of conflicting items? overwrite them or not? merge (sub-)directories?
   - in case of `E:\TEST\TEST`, do you want `E:\TEST` to be moved at once, so there is no more directory `TEST` at `E:\`?.
4. Note that the `move` command cannot be used because it causes trouble when moving directories and the destination directory already exists (`Access is denied.` errors occur).

Item **1.** can be solved by a nice work-around using `for /F` and `dir`:

```dos
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S /A:D "E:\TEST"') do echo(%%I
```

This enforces the entire directory tree to be enumerated (read) before the loop iterations start.

However, this introduces another problem similar to item **2.**: when a name is given for `dir` that matches a directory existing in the given location, its content is returned rather than all items matching that name. What I mean is the following:

- `dir /B /S /A:D "E:\"` returns all directories (`/A:D`) at `E:\` recursively (`/S`);
- `dir /B /S /A:D "E:\file.ext"` returns all directories called `file.ext`, even if there is a *file* named `E:\file.ext`;
- but: `dir /B /S /A:D "E:\TEST"` returns all *sub*-directories of `E:\TEST`, but not `E:\TEST` itself;
- however: `dir /B /S /A:D "E:\TEST*"` returns all directories *beginning* with `TEST`, also those in `E:\`; to exactly match the name `TEST`, additional filtering is required (using `findstr`);

All this means:

```dos
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S /A:D "E:\TEST*" ^| findstr /I /E /C:"\\TEST"') do echo(%%I
```

Item **3.** can only be solved by you, but to provide a complete answer, I make some assumptions:

- (sub-)directories are merged, already existing items are overwritten without notice;
- parent directories take precedence over sub-directories (like `for /R` and `dir /S` behave, because for every branch in a tree, they always go from higher down to lower directory levels);

Item **4.** can be solved by using command `robocopy` together with option `/MOVE` instead of `move`.

---

So here is the final script:

```dos
@echo off

rem // Define constants here:
set "_PATH=E:\"
set "_NAME=TEST"
set "_DEST=E:\FOUND"

2> nul mkdir "%_DEST%"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('
    dir /B /S /A:D "%_PATH%\%_NAME%*" ^| findstr /I /E /C:"\\%_NAME%"
') do (
    > nul robocopy "%%I" "%_FOUND%\%_NAME" /E /MOVE
)
```

The `> nul` portion is intended to suppress progress and log messages and to suppress `The system cannot find the path specified.` errors in case `E:\TEST\TEST` is attempted to be moved although it does no longer exist since the parent `E:\TEST` has alread been moved before.