# CMD Batch Rename not working Properly

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a file named `01_tiago_miguel.txt` and this code:

```
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in ("*_*") do (
    rem // Store current item:
    set "FILE=%%~A"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of or trouble with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Remove everything up to and including the first `_`:

    echo ren "!FILE!" "!FILE:*_=!"
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

This gives the output:

> ```
> ren "01_tiago_miguel.txt" "tiago_miguel.txt"
> ```

Which is exactly what I want - remove the first three characters.

However if I remove the `echo` it renames to `miguel.txt`, which doesn't make much sense since the output of the echo seems correct.
Any idea why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [At which point does \`for\` or \`for /R\` enumerate the directory (tree)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975093/at-which-point-does-for-or-for-r-enumerate-the-directory-tree)

Comment: Just a side note: changing the mask from `*_*` to `??_*` would help to avoid renaming files again when running the script a second time...

Comment: _…and this is why I specifically mentioned the pattern and used it in my answer to your last question_. My alternative solution would be that you move and rename to a different or holding directory so that the files cannot be reprocessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (`dir /b /a-d "*_*"') do (
```

What is happening is that your `echo` doesn't rename the file (duh) but removing it does.

`ren "01_tiago_miguel.txt" "tiago_miguel.txt"` is executed, so the new filename is `tiago_miguel.txt`,

BUT

`tiago_miguel.txt` also fits the `*_*` mask, so

`ren "tiago_miguel.txt" "miguel.txt"` is executed, so the new filename is `miguel.txt`.

Using the `dir` command does a directory list and then processes the list, so any changes made are not re-encountered.