# Remove "0" from the beginning of a file name

Tags: batch-file

A little bit of a background of what I'm trying to fix. We have files that are created daily that get dumped in a folder that's created for the current day. Some of these files get created with a 0 in front of them. So, 0123456, for example.
 I'm trying to come up with a batch script that removes the 0 from those files. I came up with this:

```
@echo off

ECHO Checking HNS for Pics that start with a "0"

For /R "D:\Shared\Quality Photos\TEST2\TEST\" %%a in (0*.*) do ren "%%a" " *.*"
```

It removes the 0 but replaces it with a space. So, I add this line to the code and it errors out:

```
For /R "D:\Shared\Quality Photos\TEST2\TEST\" %%a in ( *.*) do ren "%%a" %%a
```

Thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: Is there always only a single `0` you want to remove, or could there be more than one zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to remove all leading zeros even if there are more than one, you could try this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /S "D:\Shared\Quality Photos\TEST2\TEST\0*.*"
') do (
    for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%%~nxF") do (
        if not "%%N"=="" ren "%%F" "%%N"
    )
)
```

The inner `for /F` loop removes all leading delimiters, namely `0`, from the file names.

The `if not "%%N"==""` part is only needed in case there could occur files with a base name consisting of zeros only and without a file name extension.

---

You should not use a `for` (`/R`) loop on files which are renamed, copied or (re-)moved within the directory (tree) that is enumerated by the loop, because files might be processed twice or not at all. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093) to learn why. Using `for /F` and `dir /B` (`/S`) is a better alternative as the entire directory (tree) is enumerated before the loop starts to process any items. (In your particular case there would not be a problem since the renamed files do no longer match the pattern, given that there is always a single leading `0` only.)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (0*.*) DO (
 SET num=%%~na
 CALL ECHO(REN "%%a" "%%num:~1%%%%~xa"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Method : set `num` to the name part of the file (`%%~na`) then rename the file, removing the first character and appending the extension (`%%~xa`)