# Nested for in batch executed twice

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, nested-loops, variable-expansion

I have the following code in my batch script:

```
for %%m in (a b c) do (
    cd %%m
    dir
    for %%f in (*.zip) do rename "%%f" "%%m_%%f"
    dir
    cd ..
)
```

It is supposed to prepend the name of the folder a file lives in to the filename. I do so by running a nested for loop.

However, when I run the script I get the following outputs (shortened, for each variant of a, b, c):

```
05/15/2018  04:45 AM         5,213,422 build_1.0.0.zip
05/15/2018  04:45 AM         5,213,422 a_a_build_1.0.0.zip
```

so for whatever reason the rename gets executed two times per file and the second time on the already renamed file. With echo enabled we can actually see that happen:

```
C:\project>for %m in (a b c) do (
 cd %m     
 dir 
 for %f in (*.zip) do rename "%f" "%m_%f"  
 dir 
 cd .. 
)

...

C:\project>rename "build_1.0.0.zip" "a_build_1.0.0" 
C:\project>rename "a_build_1.0.0" "A_a_build_1.0.0"
```

Why does that happen, and how can it be fixed (I would prefer to keep the nested loop if possible, as the script is normally a little longer - but even this shortened version shows this strange behaviour)

Comment: The `for` reads the directory one filename at a time. The filename generated then seems to be a new entry in the directory, so it's reprocessed. To overcome this, use a `for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d *') do ...` as this builds a `dir` list in memory, then processes the list so the directory is not re-interpreted.

Comment: Take a look also to this post: [At which point does `for` or `for /R` enumerate the directory (tree)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093)