# Moving a batch file into directories added while the batch file is running

Tags: windows, batch-file

Say I have a filesystem like so:

```
Directory 1
  --dataset
Directory 2
  --dataset
Directory 3
  --dataset
process.bat
copier.bat <-- RUNS
```

The copier.bat copies process.bat into a directory and runs it:

```
Directory 1
  --dataset
  --process.bat <-- RUNS
Directory 2
  --dataset
Directory 3
  --dataset
process.bat
copier.bat
```

Process.bat takes a few minutes, and when it's done, copier.bat copies process.bat into the next directory and runs it:

```
Directory 1
  --dataset
  --process.bat
Directory 2
  --dataset
  --process.bat <-- RUNS
Directory 3
  --dataset
process.bat
copier.bat
```

While process.bat is running in the next directory, a new directory with another dataset is added:

```
Directory 1
  --dataset
  --process.bat
Directory 2
  --dataset
  --process.bat <-- RUNNING
Directory 3
  --dataset
Directory 4
  --dataset
process.bat
copier.bat
```

I need copier.bat to recognize Directory 4 is added while process.bat is running so it continues to copy into Directory 4 and run process.bat.

This is what copier.bat looks like right now, as it stands it will only copy into the directories present when copier.bat is first ran:

```
for /D %%i in (*) do (
cd %%i
copy ..\process.bat process.bat
call process.bat
cd ..
)
```

Code source: https://peterfalkingham.com/2018/04/01/colmap-openmvs-scripts-updated

Comment: Well, your code does not copy `process.bat` as you describe, it copies itself. And `for` or `for /D` does definitely not enumerate all matching files or directories on advance -- read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093)...

Comment: Anyway, why do you copy a sub-script into each directory? can't you just let a single script do all the tasks? You could let it create a log that indicates what directories have been processed and let it process only those items not present in the log, and let it even recheck against the log after having finished processing the initially enumerated directories, so you can assure all directories have been processed when the script quits...

Comment: Oops, it was a long day. Fixed the example so it copies process.bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:main
call :myCopier
if not errorlevel 1 goto :main

exit /b 0


:myCopier
setlocal
set "batfile=process.bat"
set "exitcode=1"

for /D %%A in (*) do (
    if not exist "%%~A\%batfile%" pushd "%%~A" && (
        set "exitcode=0"
        copy "..\%batfile%" "%batfile%" && call "%batfile%"
        popd
    )
)

exit /b %exitcode%
```

You are copying `copier.bat` in your code though
copying `process.bat` in you directory structure listings.
I consider the later as logically correct.

This code will call the label `:myCopier` in the `:main`
loop until `%errorlevel%` is not 0.

It will do `Directory 1`, `Directory 2` and `Directory 3`
on 1st `call :myCopier`. `%errorlevel%` returned is 0 so it
does another `call :myCopier`. This time `Directory 4` is
processed. `%errorlevel%` returned is 0 so it does another
`call :myCopier`. All directories will have `process.bat`
within, so the `%errorlevel%` returned is 1. This allows
the end of the `:main` loop.

With your other script. Perhaps you should insert a
`setlocal` to keep it's enviroment local to itself.
Also insert double quotes around paths so spaces
or special characters do not cause problems.