# How to rename PDFtk-server files with timestamp?

Tags: batch-file

I am using PDFtk-server to merge 2 PDF files. This creates a new PDF with name `Test_`.

Now, what I am looking for is a batch files that renames the `Test_` files to `Test_datestamp` and then move them into another folder and delete the files.

It is working if only one file is present.

```
pdftk C:\test\*.pdf C:\test\file-to-add\file.pdf cat output C:\test\output\Test_.pdf

ren "C:\test\output\*pdf" "Test_ - %date:/=.% %time::=-%.pdf"
del C:\test\*.pdf
```

Then comes to copy part to other folders.

If having multiple files, the first one gets renamed but other not, because it is trying to set the same timestamp, so I need some kind of delay between renaming.

Comment: There is a wrong file mask in your `ren` command line (it should read `*.pdf`). But why aren't you using the file `Test_.pdf` you created in the previous line? Anyway, I think what you are looking for is a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to process multiple files; you need to make sure then that you don't rename the same file twice (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093))...