# How do I prevent an infinite loop in windows batch file for in do command?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have wav files I am normalizing with ffmpeg-normalize (a python program).  My batch file is this
`for %%n in (*.wav) do ffmpeg-normalize "%%n" -nt peak -t 0 -o "%%n-norm.wav"`

In my directory of 5 files, I get 5 -norm.wav files.  Unfortunately then, the batch file creates 5 -norm.wav-norm.wav files and so on and so on.  Why wouldn't it stop at the original list of 5 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that a standard [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) does not fully enumerate the target directory in advance (see also [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093)), and that the output files also match the pattern (`*.wav`) for the input files. The first issue could be solved by using a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) that parses the output of the [`dir` command](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), so the complete file list is generated before looping even starts; the second issue could be solved by an additional filter constituted by [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to exclude output files to become reprocessed (when the script is executed more often than once):

```cmd
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*.wav" ^| findstr /V /I "-norm\.wav$"
') do (
    ffmpeg-normalize "%%F" -nt peak -t 0 -o "%%~nF-norm.wav"
)
```