# Bat file cannot get the file location

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here's snippet of the code that's giving me error!

```bash
set "inputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFile=list.txt"
if not exist temp (
    echo Input folder does not exist!
    pause
    exit /b 1
)
pushd temp
del temp\list.txt 2>nul
for %%F in (*) do (
    echo Processing: "%%F"
    echo file '%%~fF'>> temp\list.txt
)
popd
echo Completed!
pause
```

I've a Main folder in which .bat file runs, now the bat file creates temp folder and adds some files in it (done in code before this) this code should create a text file which has a list of files in temp folder in this format:
`file 'temp folder path\filename.ext'`
But instead no txt file is created and it gives me the following error:

```
Processing: "filename" (filename is correct which is present in temp folder)
The system cannot find the patch specified.
```

Can you guys tell me what's wrong?

I also tried `~dp0` (which is set) thing but by doing so it fails in if statement!
Then I tried direct approach and instead of using set values I used dir paths.

In short:
I was trying to create a text file that lists all the files in a folder automatically.

Comment: Just `temp` is a relative path, relative to the *current working folder*, which might not be identical to the *location of your script* (`%~dp0`). To be sure you are where you think you are, set the working folder to the script location: `cd /d "%~dp0"`

Comment: nope it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There could be used following in the batch file:

```
set "inputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFile=%outputFolder%\list.txt"

pushd "%inputFolder%" 2>nul && goto ProcessFiles
echo Input folder does not exist!
pause
exit /b 1

:ProcessFiles
del /A /F "%outputFile%" 2>nul
for %%G in (*) do (
    echo Processing: "%%G"
    echo file '%%~fG'>>"%outputFile%"
)
popd
echo Completed!
pause
```

It is also possible to use:

```
set "inputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFile=%outputFolder%\list.txt"

if exist "%inputFolder%\" goto ProcessFiles
echo Input folder does not exist!
pause
exit /b 1

:ProcessFiles
del /A /F "%outputFile%" 2>nul
for %%G in ("%inputFolder%\*") do (
    echo Processing: "%%~nxG"
    echo file '%%G'>>"%outputFile%"
)
echo Completed!
pause
```

The main difference between the two variants is that the second one does not change the current working directory at all.

Please read the **issue** chapters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564).

**Note:** The file `list.txt` created also in subdirectory `temp` of the batch file directory will be also listed inside `list.txt`. It can even happen that another file is missing instead in `list.txt` or the loop is endless running if the drive is using FAT32 or exFAT instead of NTFS as file system. The output file should be created in a different directory or a different **FOR** loop is used which first gets all files names in the subdirectory `temp` loaded into memory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and then **FOR** processes this captured list of file names as shown below with the next two batch file solutions.

See also: [At which point does `for` or `for /R` enumerate the directory (tree)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975093/)

The first batch file with `list.txt` created also in input folder in a fail-safe manner not listing `list.txt` in the list file:

```
set "inputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFile=%outputFolder%\list.txt"

pushd "%inputFolder%" 2>nul && goto ProcessFiles
echo Input folder does not exist!
pause
exit /b 1

:ProcessFiles
del /A /F "%outputFile%" 2>nul
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%G in ('dir /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    echo Processing: "%%G"
    echo file '%%~fG'>>"%outputFile%"
)
popd
echo Completed!
pause
```

Files with hidden attribute are also included in the list. Modify `/A-D` to `/A-D-H` to exclude hidden files like **FOR** does it.

The second batch file with `list.txt` created also in input folder in a fail-safe manner not listing `list.txt` in the list file:

```
set "inputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFolder=%~dp0temp"
set "outputFile=%outputFolder%\list.txt"

if exist "%inputFolder%\" goto ProcessFiles
echo Input folder does not exist!
pause
exit /b 1

:ProcessFiles
del /A /F "%outputFile%" 2>nul
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%G in ('dir "%inputFolder%\*" /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    echo Processing: "%%~nxG"
    echo file '%%G'>>"%outputFile%"
)
echo Completed!
pause
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also: [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) which explains the conditional command operator `&&`.